# Make GDB print context around every time

Tags: gdb

LLDB print context around current line every time like this:

```
     int a = 12;
     int b = a * 13;
->   printf("%d\n", b);
     return 0;
   }
```

In the same time, GDB just print one current line:

```
->   printf("%d\n", b);
```

Can I make GDB print context every step like LLDB? Googling give all around list command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a way to accomplish this might be by defining a macro that redefines a keyword, such as 's' or 'n'.
for example, if you wanted to print out the value of the stack pointer at each step you could redefine 's' by entering these lines into the (gbd) console:

```
def s
step
info registers sp
end
```

now every time you use the command 's' you actually do a step and print of the sp register

Comment: But there is not fancy -> unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this.

You could maybe make it work, sort of, using hookpost-stop to invoke an explicit list command.

I think most people just use one of the many gdb GUIs instead, though.

Comment: Can you gove me a list of these good GUIs? Emacs? DDD? Netbeans/eclipse?

Comment: I'm partial to Emacs, but there is a reasonably complete list here: http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/GDB%20Front%20Ends